# Laravel - bug with echoing var in view

Tags: php, laravel

This code outputs exactly what I want to type on page

```
{{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->first()->avatar) }}
```

So exactly:

[image]

It looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 section-count text-center my-auto small-text p-margin0">
   <b>{{ $topic->views }}</b>
   <p>WYŚWIETLEŃ {{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->first()->avatar) }}
</div>
```

But when I remove laravel's "dd" to look it like:

`<p>WYŚWIETLEŃ {{ $users->where('id', $user_id)->first()->avatar }}`

Suddenly... there is crash splash bum error...

[image]

Before I tried to do it even like:

`<p>WYŚWIETLEŃ {{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->values()[0]->avatar) }}`

Works again.
On Page

[image]

Okay, so let's delete dd :)!

`<p>WYŚWIETLEŃ {{ $users->where('id', $user_id)->values()[0]->avatar }}`

crash splash bum error... :<

Now this;

[image]

What is this??? It's everything correct when I dump it by dd, and without errors :<.

---

edit

$users var is collection, looks like this

[image]

Comment: Can you add description about `$users` variable ?

Comment: @SagarGautam updated

Comment: try to dump just `$users->where('id', $user_id)->values()`  e.g `{{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->values()) }}`

Comment: @ManpreetSingh It doesn't give me what I want, it's collection. I need avatar

Comment: can you post `{{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->values()) }}` this data please ?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh here  you are `http://imgur.com/a/CUhfK`

Comment: @AngielskiUzet okay then why are you adding `where()` and then `first()` ?
`$users->avatar` doesn't give what you want ?

Comment: @SagarGautam because without it $users contains array of many users, look `http://imgur.com/a/IwzPB`

Comment: ok try this `$users->where('id', $user_id)->get()[0]->avatar`

Comment: @ManpreetSingh `http://imgur.com/a/37Fwg`

Comment: oopss sorry  my fault : try this : `$users->where('id', $user_id)->get()->toArray()[0]->avatar`;

Wait are you using `laravel 5.4` ?

Comment: @AngielskiUzet Are sure user exist for $user_id ?

Comment: @ManpreetSingh http://imgur.com/a/vpp8g

Comment: @AngielskiUzet if it doesn't work please dump this `{{$users->where('id', $user_id)->get()->toArray()[0]}}` post the full image

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, I'm 100% sure :)

Comment: @ManpreetSingh cannot dump this because http://imgur.com/a/jk3ti Error with dd()

Comment: Lol an other solution maybe this `{{DB:table("users")->where("id", $user_id)->get()->toArray()[0]->avatar;}}` if it doesn't work please give me output of `{{DB:table("users")->where("id", $user_id)->get()}}`

Comment: @AngielskiUzet quit strange problem then. Basically `Trying to get property of non object` appears when result is null or not an object. But in your case user exists as you say. It's strange problem

Comment: I finally found what happened. Your all time asking about if I'm sure about user exists caused I started to doubt if I'm 100% sure and my checking was right. And I started to check if my algorythm works 100% right, you pushed me to this. And I found that problem was, that not all topics have first post. There were some topics without any first post. And I added them and It works now. Thank you very much :) you have great nose :D Respect

Comment: @ManpreetSingh thank you very much for your help, time and trouble :). Sagar found my bug, smelled it :). Thank you very much for your help and trying to fix my problem dude :).

Comment: @AngielskiUzet Any way Congrats man :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay the first thing you need to do, is that you have to make a check if the user actually exists, so always before calling this, make something like:

```
@if($user = $users->where('id', $user_id)->first())
   <p>WYŚWIETLEŃ {{ $user->avatar }}</p>
@endif
```

Otherwise, would be good if you can check before this what is this query actually giving you ( might give you null when you use this on collection and not Builder ), so like this:

```
{{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->first()) }}
```

Comment: This user exist 100%. This doesn't help me

Comment: What does {{ dd($users->where('id', $user_id)->first()) }}  give you, can I have a screen shot ?